# LibreOffice calc Hyperlink from macro doesn't work

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have trouble making hyperlink within macro.

For example just create empty spreadsheet and create another sheet within so we have 2 empty sheets.

In Sheet1 A:1 just paste `=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2")`

For A:3 create macro and execute it

```
Sub TestMacro
    dim document as object
    oSheet = thiscomponent.sheets.getByName("Sheet1")
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("$A$3")
    xx="=HYPERLINK(""#Sheet2"")"
    oCell.setString(xx)
End Sub
```

So sheet1 now have something on cell A1 and A3. the both should be link but just A1 works.
If jou press CTRL+click on Sheet1 A1 the Sheet2 is selected.
If you press CTRL+click on Sheet1 A3 nothing happens

I tested ou xubuntu 18.04LTS
LibreOffice Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10

Comment: After upgrading to Version: 6.3.3.2 Build ID: 1:6.3.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 the issue still remain

Answer (score 1):

For functions and calculations, set the cell formula instead of a literal string value.

```
oCell.setFormula(xx)
```

Comment: It may worth to mention that if you have LibreOffice localized in other languages the functions must be set in english with setFormula(...) (i. e. setting =HYPERLINK instead of =HIPERVINCULO that would be in spanish).